# Cross-module reference resolution error from SV wait statement

Tags: system-verilog

I wanted to wait on the output variable of a task.
eg: `wait(user_defined_task_name(output_variable_type_name) == 1)`

In this example shown below, my intention is to make `wait` statement to be active from 0ns to 3ns (basically from the beginning of timestamp till t2=1)

Here is a working example;

```
class cl;
  task run(output bit t);
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
    #1;
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
    #2;
    t = 1;
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
  endtask
endclass

class c2 extends cl;
  bit t2;
  task run1();
    wait(run(t2) == 1); // error from this line, what am i violating here?
    $display("t2 working t2=%0b time = %0t", t2, $realtime);
     
  endtask
endclass

module tmp;
  c2 c2_h=new;
  initial begin 
    c2_h.run1();
    $display("test msg");
  end
endmodule
```

eda output log:

> Top Level Modules:
> tmp TimeScale is 1 ns / 1 ns
>
> Error-[XMREF] Cross-module reference resolution error testbench.sv, 19
> Cross-module reference resolution error is found.   Function is
> expected, but actual target is not a function.   Source info:
> run(this.t2)
>
> 1 error CPU time: .116 seconds to compile Exit code expected: 0,
> received: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems with your code. A `task` does not return a value and cannot be used in an expression. You can only call it as a stand alone statement. But if you change `run` to a `function` functions cannot consume time.

In your particular example, you do not change the value of the `t` argument until the end of the task, and `output` arguments are copied out upon exiting the task, so you might as well just call the task `run(t2)` as a statement and it will block until returning.

```
task run1();
    run(t2);
    $display("t2 working t2=%0b time = %0t", t2, $realtime);     
endtask
```

If on the otherhand `run` set the `t` argument somewhere in the middle of the task, and you want to continue the `run1` task as soon as that happened, the you would have use a `fork/join_none` and a `ref` argument instead.

```
class cl;
  task run(ref bit t);
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
    #1;
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
    #2;
    t = 1;
    #2;
    $display("time=%0t , t=%0b",$realtime, t); 
  endtask
endclass

class c2 extends cl;
  bit t2;
  task run1();
    fork
      run(t2);
    join_none
    wait(t2 == 1);
    $display("t2 working t2=%0b time = %0t", t2, $realtime);
     
  endtask
endclass
```

Comment: "A task does not return a value and cannot be used in an expression." - answers my question.   Bonus take away points; (1) task as a statement blocks until returning, (2) I can also make things run concurrently using `fork join_none` and `ref` . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code on the Cadence simulator, I get a different message:

```
xmvlog: *E,INVCTX The task 'run' cannot be used in this context.
```

Using the `nchelp` utility to get more information on that message:

> A task or void function cannot be passed as an actual argument
> because they do not return a value that can be used. They also cannot
> be used as part of an expression.

In your simple example, there seems to be no need to use `wait`.  You can simply call the task on its own:

```
  task run1();
    run(t2);
    $display("t2 working t2=%0b time = %0t", t2, $realtime);     
  endtask
```